# how to resolve python selenium no such element error?

Tags: python, selenium, security, automation, webautomation

```
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.canva.com/q/pro-signup/")
time.sleep(6)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name('rbV9vo63iaj7sGd7XwS4h'))
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("//iframe[contains(@name, '_hjRemote')]")
```

It cant find element last line. i tried contains, starts with and indexing but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using different elements such as the xpath or the id. If that fails then you could select the element by the css selector. If that fails then you could always use a lib like pyautogui to physically click on the web element.

Comment: elements are dynamic. having it stored in a var for switching later.

Comment: is it a link or what is it?

Answer (score 1):

There are total of 6 iframes, The elements you are looking, they are inside

```
iframe[src^='https://www.canva.com/']
```

this iframe.

so you need to switch to this frame first  :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[src^='https://www.canva.com/']"))
```

I would use the below code to click on `Sign up with email`:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.canva.com/q/pro-signup/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src^='https://www.canva.com/']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Sign up with email']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In case you want to have a predefined iframe stored, you could something like this :

```
remote_vars_frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[id='_hjRemoteVarsFrame']")
driver.switch_to.frame(remote_vars_frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this Exception by directly searching for the element without switching to any iframe as below

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("//iframe[contains(@name, '_hjRemote')]")
```